# Is pspdf works for native js

Tags: pspdfkit

I need to implement an pdf viewer in javascript/dojo mobile, which have all controls and opting for pspdfkit.

Does pspdfkit supports for native `js / dojo`. Founf it only for native iOS, android and cordova plugins.

Please suggest on this.

Answer (score -1):

Head of PSPDFKit here.

We do offer SDKs for PDF viewing, editing, form filling, digital signatures and indexed full-text search currently for both iOS and Android. We offer iOS since 2011 and in early 2015 released our first version of Android - now both SDKs are mature and a whole team is working on them.

For Cordova we have wrappers for both platforms:
https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/other-languages/apache-cordova-phonegap/

If you have any further questions feel free to contact us at our support platform at https://pspdfkit.com/support/request directly. We do not monitor StackOverflow so answers might take much longer than with our support system.